# Select All Values From Table That Match All Values of Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a list of values that is returned from a subquery and would like to select all values from another table that match the values of that subquery. Is there a particular way that's best to go about this?

So far I've tried:

```
select * from table where tableid = select * from table1 where tableid like '%this%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table where tableid in(select tableid 
from table1 
where tableid like '%this%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where tableid IN 
(select tableid from table1 where tableid like '%this%')
```

A sub-query needs to return what you are asking for.  Additionally, if there's more than 1 result, you need `IN` rather than `=`

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
  select * from table where tableid in
       (select tableid from table1 where tableid like '%this%')
```

`=` works when subquery returns 1 record only
`in`  works when subquery returns 1 or more than one record only

Answer (score 0):

I am reading a SQL Server book right now, and it highlights doing this using the `EXISTS` statement in the `WHERE` clause for speed and efficiency purposes. Here's a potential solution.

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
    tableName AS t
WHERE
    EXISTS(
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            table1 AS s --as in subtable or something like that
        WHERE
            t.tableid = s.tableid
                AND
            s.tableid like '%this%'
            )
```